# how i can load file from WebBrowser in codename App

Tags: codenameone

I was using the input type="file" on the WebBrowser component , but It doesn't work.

my question is how i can load a file from my mobile using html/php page to the cloud or any site web that hosting that page web

**edit:**

i want to upload a file from my mobile to my router through html page that is hosted in my router

i am using android 4.4 in real device and JDK 8_66

Answer (score 2):

This is how you properly execute browser component in CN1:

```
 Form myBrowserForm = new Form("Browser Test");
 myBrowserForm.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 myBrowserForm.show();

 final BrowserComponent wb = new BrowserComponent();
 myBrowserForm.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, wb);

 final Dialog ipDlg = new InfiniteProgress().showInifiniteBlocking();
 wb.setURL("https://www.codenameone.com");
 wb.addWebEventListener("onLoad", new ActionListener() {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            ipDlg.dispose();
      }
 });
```

Comment: I would also recommend using JDK 8 so we are sure that the JavaFX libraries are available. If an older VM or OpenJDK is used then the native browser component might fail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but that code also don't work, i have edited my question

Comment: Must you do it through html page? or you're open to other methods?

Comment: In that case, use MultipartRequest. What type of file is it?